# ext and project.ext have same scope in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

If I have below Android gradle script;

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 25
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.compileSdkVersion 
}
```

1. Does `ext {...}` have same scope as `project.ext {...}`?
2. Does below two have same scope?

   - `compileSdkVersion project.compileSdkVersion`
   - `compileSdkVersion this.compileSdkVersion`
   - `compileSdkVersion compileSdkVersion` - Nope. this gives error

Answer (score 5):

You can [check the doc:](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:declaring_variables)

> **Extra properties**
>   All enhanced objects in Gradle’s **domain model** can hold extra user-defined properties. This includes, but is not limited to, projects, tasks, and source sets. Extra properties can be added, read and set via the owning object’s ext property. Alternatively, an ext block can be used to add multiple properties at once.

In your code, the `ext` block adds two extra properties to the `project` object.

Also the `ext` is shorthand for `project.ext`. 
To read an extra property, the `ext` is omitted and you can use something like:

- `project.myExtProp`
- `myExtProp`

In your case you can use:

```
compileSdkVersion project.compileSdkVersion
```

because the extra properties has the same name of the android properties.

Just a last consideration.
Defining in the root level file something like:

```
ext {
   compileSdkVersion=26
}
```

you are adding the extra properties to the `rootProject` object.
It means that in your module/build.gradle file you can retrieve this value using `rootProject.ext`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
}
```

Comment: Thanks. and what about `this.myExtProp`? is it same as `project` scope in the script file?